# .NET Core Crossgen2 compilation without IL code

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Is there a way to get Crossgen2 to compile an assembly without including managed (IL) code?

My project type: Blazor Server (.NET 6.0).

I activate use Crossgen2 with ReadyToRun settings:

```
<PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
```

but the assembly still contains managed (IL) code.

Comment: Feature, not a bug.  The goal was to *reduce* jitting, not to eliminate it.  Generics and Reflection being the trouble spots.  Counter-example is .NET Native, an aggressive AOT, having to baby-sit the rd.xml file can be quite a slog.

Comment: take a look at [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtimelab/tree/feature/NativeAOT-LLVM) for WebAssembly projects and [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtimelab/tree/feature/NativeAOT) for normal projects. its just support console apps for now

Comment: have you found any solution to this problem?